# SQL Dev. can't connect to DB, yet SQLPLUS can

Tags: sql, oracle, connection, sqlplus

I've already seen a similar question but couldn't find a solution.

I can successfully connect to Oracle DB through SQL*PLUS as the following image shows

[I get successfully a connection through SQL PLUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/012WG.png)

but when I tried to get a connection through SQL DEVELOPER, using the same id/pwd it returns an error code:

[I can get no connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fauIz.png)

This is my tns configuration:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\DB_Home\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SID = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Any help? I've already seen a similar question and followed their advice, but did not work to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to log in to database as SYS with Oracle SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129664/unable-to-log-in-to-database-as-sys-with-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: No solution found