# Oracle Unable to make a new connection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have installed `oracle database` and `oracle sql developer`. When I try to connect I am getting the below error

[image]

> Status: Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
> ORA-12505, TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
> (CONNECTION_ID=E2rGqMoxSoqYb2fJOCTRbw==)

**transnames.orc**

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: 
C:\app\Faisal\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))


 ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC))
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = CLRExtProc)
  (PRESENTATION = RO)
  )
  )

  ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
  )
  )
```

**listner.ora**

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: 
C:\app\Faisal\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
 (SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Faisal\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
  (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Faisal\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
  )
  )

  LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
   (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
  )
  (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  )
  )
  ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\Faisal
```

**NET Manager**

[image]

**CMD**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 03-JUN-2022 17:33:53

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1522)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00511: No listener
64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                03-JUN-2022 17:04:13
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 29 min. 39 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\app\Faisal\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         d:\app\faisal\diag\tnslsnr\Faisal\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 3 handler(s) for this service...
Service "sd" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "sd", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "sdXDB" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "sd", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: port 1522 or 1521, make up your mind :) Also, your SID would either bye 'sd' or 'sdXDB' - NOT 'orcl'

Comment: @thatjeffsmith the port 1522 and 1521 are set by default. also by changing the `SID` to `sd` not it gives me `Status: Failure -Test failed: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` with username `sys as sysdba` and pw `Adpoly123`

Comment: that's good! you've got the right database connection setup now. BUT, do NOT login as SYS. Login as a 'normal' user, and you should be just fine.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith actually I am new to oracle so didn't know the db username and password :(

Comment: set username to sys, set role to 'SYSDBA' - and make sure sql developer is running on the same machine as your database, otherwise you'll have to do some database configuration to allow for remote logins

Comment: @thatjeffsmith can you pl share the command :|

Comment: @thatjeffsmith i have done `SQL> create user system identified by sd123;
create user system identified by sd123`  but when I am trying to connect it says `Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43787514/3061852) for more about logging in with SYS AS SYSDBA using SQL Developer.

Comment: @kfinity tried but still not resolved

Comment: You can check out the `local_listener` by using `SQL> show parameter local_l` after connecting to the DB by using `C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqlplus / as sysdba`. You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63459252/5841306) in order to see the method to register the `local_listener`, ignoring pluggable database. By the way, don't try to cretae the `system` user as commented above, since it's a default user.

Comment: I already checked this case yesterday, seems you need to register the local listener after restarting it, **but** firstly there seems to be problem with skew ports(they're different) those you need to fix as @thatjeffsmith already pointed out, perhaps you'll not need to register the `local_listener` after fixing that confliction.

Comment: Well, you can try to perform those explained directives please

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

1- the listener is started

2- provide correct SID or Service Name: meaning, if these 2 are different dont use the name of the SID while checking the Service Name checkbox.

3-make sure you have the ping of the server you are reaching (direct access, if not do the tunneling)

4- make sure you are using the correct port

5- make sure you are not using PDB and you have created your own database! (PDBs always go south)

These are the reasons you see that error